# Como obter o valor do checkbox e option com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e cada checkbox corresponde ao valor

```
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="serie2" id="serie2[3]" name="serie2[3]">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" class="serie2" id="serie2[4]" name="serie2[4]">
<input type="checkbox" value="5" class="serie2" id="serie2[5]" name="serie2[5]">
```

sucessivamente ... vindo do php :

```
echo "<label><i><input type='checkbox' name='serie2[$lnSer[ser_cod]]' id='serie2[$lnSer[ser_cod]]' class='serie2' value='$lnSer[ser_cod]' $marca>$lnSer[ser_descr]</i></label>";
```

seguinte, se na minha função Ajax eu definir a variável assim : var serie  = '5,17,14'; ok, mais quando tento percorrer utilizando a funcão abaixo, ocorre o problema:

```
var serie = [];
        $(".serie2:checked").each(function() {
        serie.push(this.value);
    });
```

como obtenho o valor no formato var serie  = '5,17,14' ?

mesma coisa opção no option  :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

se eu definir o valor como var curso = 'I|25|TU-II|2|TU'; passa !

como obtenho o valor do value desse campo, ficando nesse formato curso = 'I|25|TU-II|2|TU'

```
<option value="3|1|2">CICLOS E PRÁTICAS DOCENTES  | Turma 2 |   </option>
<option value="3|1|5">CICLOS E PRÁTICAS DOCENTES  | Turma 5 |   </option>
```

Obrigado

Comment: No final voce quer o id dos checkboxes selecionados todos na mesma string separados por virgula, e no caso do select sao os ids separados por `|`, eh isso?

Comment: já tentou usar a função "Join" ? Ela converte um array em uma string, separando os elementos pelo argumento enviado para a função. variavel.join(", ");

Answer (score 1):

Para obter valores selecionados de um `<select>`:

```
  $('select option:selected').each(function(){
      resultado = resultado +'|' + this.value;
  });
```

Veja o [JsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/n26y02hm/) funcionando.

Comment: Obrigado Thiago, deu certo, fiz para a opção do curso:

var curso0 = '';
  $('#curso0 option:selected').each(function(){
   curso0 += this.value;
   
  });
  
  var curso1 = '';
  $('#curso1 option:selected').each(function(){
   curso1 += this.value;
   
  });

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo ainda com a duvida que levantei acho que consigo propor uma solucao. Ao inves de acumular o resultado, voce pode obter uma lista com tudo o que quer e entao transformar os resultados da forma que achar adequada. No caso dos checkboxes:

```
var lista = $(".serie2")
              .filter(':checked')           // filtra pelos checados
              .map(function(idx, element) { // transforma a lista
                return element.value;       // nesse exemplo, uma lista de valores
              })
```

Na funcao que voce passa para o metodo `map` voce especifica como gerar uma nova lista, do jeito que quiser. Quanto ao select, mesmo principio:

```
var lista = $('select option:selected')
                .map(function(idx, el) { 
                    return el.value;
                })
```

Agora voce pode criar uma string da forma que achar apropriada (tipo usando `join`, como sugerido), ou qualquer outra coisa. O interessante eh que assim voce esta trabalhando de forma declarativa ao inves de imperativa :)

Comment: Obrigado Juliano, mas ocorreu o erro quando implementei a opção do check 
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

Comment: Isso indica que algum elemento esta sendo manipulado da forma errada, tipo um objeto do jQuery sendo usado como um DOM Element